# s:iterator:- Displaying 1500 records in form .Page is breaking

Tags: jsp, struts2

Thanks in advance.
1. I have list containing the beans. I need to display all the records for editing the user.
2. I used s:iterator for display.
Problem :- 
1. For loading those many records,it is taking lot of time to load page
2. After loading the jsp page, while submit page crashed.

Please help to design proper way in this case.
Constrains from business :- 
1. user can edit the record 
2. add/delete the new record to existing list
3. add bulk data to list by file upload

Sample code:-

```
     <s:hidden id="contractChargeDtlsDTOList[%{#stat.index}].modeOfOper" 
                        name="contractChargeDtlsDTOList[%{#stat.index}].modeOfOper" value="%{modeOfOper}" />

     <s:textfield id="contractChargeDtlsDTOList[%{#stat.index}].billToCustomerId" cssStyle="display:none" theme="simple"
                            name="contractChargeDtlsDTOList[%{#stat.index}].billToCustomerId" value="%{billToCustomerId}"/>

    <s:hidden id="contractChargeDtlsDTOList[%{#stat.index}].sizeOfRatesList" 
                        name="contractChargeDtlsDTOList[%{#stat.index}].sizeOfRatesList" value="%{sizeOfRatesList}" />

    <s:hidden id="contractChargeDtlsDTOList[%{#stat.index}].proformaCount" 
                        name="contractChargeDtlsDTOList[%{#stat.index}].proformaCount" value="%{proformaCount}" />

     <s:hidden id="contractChargeDtlsDTOList[%{#stat.index}].contractDtlSeq" 
                        name="contractChargeDtlsDTOList[%{#stat.index}].contractDtlSeq" value="%{contractDtlSeq}" />

    <s:hidden id="contractChargeDtlsDTOList[%{#stat.index}].totalDiscType" 
                        name="contractChargeDtlsDTOList[%{#stat.index}].totalDiscType" value="%{totalDiscType}" />
    <s:hidden id="contractChargeDtlsDTOList[%{#stat.index}].totalDiscRate" 
                        name="contractChargeDtlsDTOList[%{#stat.index}].totalDiscRate" value="%{totalDiscRate}" />
   <s:hidden id="contractChargeDtlsDTOList[%{#stat.index}].totalAdditionalFreeDays" 
                        name="contractChargeDtlsDTOList[%{#stat.index}].totalAdditionalFreeDays" value="%{totalAdditionalFreeDays}" />

     <s:hidden id="contractChargeDtlsDTOList[%{#stat.index}].copyContractRef" 
                        name="contractChargeDtlsDTOList[%{#stat.index}].copyContractRef" value="%{copyContractRef}" />                  
    <s:hidden id="contractChargeDtlsDTOList[%{#stat.index}].copyPriceChgId" 
                        name="contractChargeDtlsDTOList[%{#stat.index}].copyPriceChgId" value="%{copyPriceChgId}" />

     <s:hidden id="contractChargeDtlsDTOList[%{#stat.index}].relativeContractDtlSeq" 
                        name="contractChargeDtlsDTOList[%{#stat.index}].relativeContractDtlSeq" value="%{relativeContractDtlSeq}" />
     <s:hidden id="contractChargeDtlsDTOList[%{#stat.index}].stdTariffChgId" 
                        name="contractChargeDtlsDTOList[%{#stat.index}].stdTariffChgId" value="%{stdTariffChgId}" />

     <tr>   
      <s:hidden id="contractChargeDtlsDTOList[%{#stat.index}].lumpsumPeriodicity" 
                        name="contractChargeDtlsDTOList[%{#stat.index}].lumpsumPeriodicity" value="%{lumpsumPeriodicity}" />
     <s:hidden id="contractChargeDtlsDTOList[%{#stat.index}].lumpsumAmount" 
                        name="contractChargeDtlsDTOList[%{#stat.index}].lumpsumAmount" value="%{lumpsumAmount}" />
      <s:if test="%{!renewalFlag}">
        <td><s:div theme="simple" id="contractChargeDtlsDTOList[%{#stat.index}].selectedSpan" >
        <s:checkbox theme="simple" name="contractChargeDtlsDTOList[%{#stat.index}].selected" onclick="checkOnSelectAll(chgListSize,'contractChargeDtlsDTOList',selectAllChgCodes);" 
                    id="contractChargeDtlsDTOList[%{#stat.index}].selected"/>
                    </s:div></td>     
        </s:if>           
        <td nowrap="nowrap" width="200"><s:textfield id="contractChargeDtlsDTOList[%{#stat.index}].chargeCode" theme="simple" onblur="populateChargeDesc(%{#stat.index})"
                name="contractChargeDtlsDTOList[%{#stat.index}].chargeCode" value="%{chargeCode}" cssStyle="width: 150px;" cssClass="inputCaps"
                    onchange="replaceSpacesObjectUpper(this,true);"/>
                <span id="contractChargeDtlsDTOList[<s:property value="#stat.index"/>].chgCodeDialodDIV">
                   <sj:a  onclick="assignRowIndex(%{#stat.index});loadChargeCodes(%{#stat.index});"  href="#">
                        <img align="absmiddle" src="images/bttns/bttn-lookup.gif" alt="" />
                   </sj:a>
                 </span>
        </td>
        <s:hidden id="contractChargeDtlsDTOList[%{#stat.index}].chargeCalcType" 
                        name="contractChargeDtlsDTOList[%{#stat.index}].chargeCalcType" value="%{chargeCalcType}" />
        <s:hidden id="contractChargeDtlsDTOList[%{#stat.index}].chargeCalcTypeDesc" 
                        name="contractChargeDtlsDTOList[%{#stat.index}].chargeCalcTypeDesc" value="%{chargeCalcTypeDesc}"/>                         

        <td>
             <span id="contractChargeDtlsDTOList[<s:property value="#stat.index"/>].chargeDescription">
                    <s:property  value="%{chargeDescription}" />
             </span>

             <s:textfield  theme="simple" id="contractChargeDtlsDTOList[%{#stat.index}].chargeDescriptionText"
             name="contractChargeDtlsDTOList[%{#stat.index}].chargeDescription" value="%{chargeDescription}" 
                        cssStyle="display:none" />

       </td>
      <s:if test="%{!stdTariff}">
        <td nowrap="nowrap" ><s:textfield id="contractChargeDtlsDTOList[%{#stat.index}].billToCustomerName" theme="simple"
                            name="contractChargeDtlsDTOList[%{#stat.index}].billToCustomerName" value="%{billToCustomerName}" cssStyle="width: 75px;" cssClass="inputs"/>
            <sj:a href="#" id="billLink1" onclick="assignRowIndex(%{#stat.index});openCodeDetail('BTC');"><img align="absmiddle" src="images/bttns/bttn-lookup.gif" alt="" /></sj:a>
        </td>  
      </s:if>       
        <td><sj:datepicker name="contractChargeDtlsDTOList[%{#stat.index}].validFrom" size="10" cssClass="inputs" value="%{validFrom}"
                            showOn="focus" label="DD/MM/YYYY" displayFormat="dd/mm/yy" changeMonth="true" changeYear="true"/></td>            
        <td><sj:datepicker name="contractChargeDtlsDTOList[%{#stat.index}].validTo" size="10" cssClass="inputs" value="%{validTo}"
                            showOn="focus" label="DD/MM/YYYY" displayFormat="dd/mm/yy" changeMonth="true" changeYear="true"/></td>
        <td><s:div theme="simple" id="contractChargeDtlsDTOList[%{#stat.index}].editedSpan" style="display:none">
                <img align="absmiddle" src="images/edited.gif" alt="" /></s:div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="Price" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default" 
                            onclick="openPriceDialog('<s:property value="%{#stat.index}"/>')">

    </tr>        
    </s:iterator>
```

Comment: Why did the page crash? What is the error? Arun below suggested using jQuery grid, this is probably a good UI choice but does not address the logic on the server which might be the issue.

Comment: Why dont you use Ajax to load the list with database paging

Answer (score 0):

you have to use page navigation pattern for solve this problem, you can create your own page navigation grid or use some ready made 3rd party struts2 plugin

Like:
[Struts2 Jquery Grid](http://www.weinfreund.de/struts2-jquery-grid-showcase/index.action)

Comment: I did not get any error at server.
1. In my requirement, user have choice of uploading of selecting the records either from LOV or laod from XL.
2. I need to fetch the details of selected values , and display the details to user.
3.Then user will edit the details and click on save in one shot.
4. I have written lot of JAVA script also, After removing the script, Iam able to proceed the functionaly . But loading the page is very slow.